# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: nomor in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\tabel.php on line 19

Tags: php

I am just learning PHP, and I just found an error in my first lesson, I had a few hours to try but do not know the solution.

`<td><?php echo $nomor=$nomor+1; ?></td>`

my php code:

```
<?php
include "koneksi.php";
$query=mysql_query("select * from biodata");
$jumlah=mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "Jumlah data ada : ".$jumlah;
?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Nomor</th><th>Nama</th><th>Alamat</th><th>Usia</th><th>Aksi</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $nomor=$nomor+1; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['nama']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['alamat']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['usia']; ?></td>
<td>
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin?')">Delete</a>
<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Update</a>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
</table><br /> 
<a href="form.php">Input data form</a>
```

thanks before

Comment: Have you tried initializing $nomor to 0?

Comment: You need to actually have a variable with that name, before you can start adding 1 to it ?

Comment: Initialise `$nomor=0;` before your `while` loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: declare the variable somewhere above line 19 and use `$nomor++;`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialize `$nomor` variable so, php interpreter, doesn't know what is `$nomor` first time it "read" it

Modify your code that way

```
<?php
  $nomor=0;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much
I did not realize that, sorry still a newbie to the geek hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
$nomor = $nomor + 1;
         ^^^^^^--- this is the EXACT spot of the error
```

You're trying to increment a variable that hasn't been defined yet. PHP has to **READ** the value in $nomor before it can +1 it, but $nomor hasn't been defined, so it doesn't exist, causing the warning. If you had:

```
$nomor = 0;
$nomor = $nomor + 1;
```

then there wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The notice can be safely ignored but what it is saying is that $nomar was never initialized. In php initialization is done by assignment. So to make the notice go away just do `$nomar = 0;`
The notice is coming from the reference on the right hand side of the assignment command, in initializing the variable it is using the variable which at that time is not initialized hence the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to PHP world.

Before ever using a variable in a process for the first time, you should define it first.

It won't result into an error, but a notice.

before using the $nomor = $nomor + 1

you have to define $nomor = 0; first out of the while loop.

Good Luck

Comment: this isn't a php concept, but about every language (more or less)

Comment: agree, we are in case of PHP now, so I had to point it out :)